# How can I post links to YouTube videos in YouTube comments?

Tags: youtube

Here is an example of someone who has posted a link to another YouTube video in a comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kPyrq6SEL0&lc=z13qe524mnnzzzl5f04cdnrhgy3vi1zjk50

I tried to post a link to a video, but when I view the comment in a private browser session, it's hidden.

Comment: What browser, device, and OS are you using? Posting the URL of a YouTube video in a comment should work, and not be hidden. Are you using any ad-blockers, anti-virus tools, or other software, add-ons, or plugs-ins that might have hidden the link?

Comment: Chrome, Windows 8. Not blocked as I can see the link from someone else in the example, but not mine in a private browser session. Add-ons don't run in a private session. My other comments are visible, even with external links to PDF files. Just not with YouTube links.

Comment: Where is your comment, or what video did you leave a comment under, and under what name?

Comment: It was a reply to the linked comment. It doesn't show for you or in a private browser window.

Comment: THIS WORKS :: copy the "share" link and paste that, instead of the URL in the address bar; so your link would be something like: https://youtu.be/yHF6RtjZyo8 ... This only works if the channel owner has not restricted comment links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, comments with links are held for approval. The video owner must approve your comment in order for it to be shown.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4409780?ref_topic=6011167

> - Held for review tab: Review comments that are held for approval based on your comment settings. You can approve or deny these comment to be published, either individually or in bulk.
> - Marked as spam tab: Review comments that are marked as spam. You can approve or deny these comment to be published, either individually or in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted in your comment does seem to appear. (Posting this as an answer since posting images in comments in not possible.)

[image]

Comment: That's not my comment. My comment with a YouTube link does not appear. That was an example of someone else posting a YouTube link, which was the first sentence in my question.

Comment: Try posting a link to your comment containing the YouTube link in question. If others can see the link, but you cannot, then the problem likely lies somewhere with your software/hardware or account.